# Bundling Firebase NodeJS SDK with Webpack

Tags: node.js, firebase, webpack, firebase-admin

I'm trying to bundle a NodeJS project (for AWS Lambda) that references the [firebase-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) NPM project. When running webpack, it fails with

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@firebase/app' in '/XXX/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js 1:0-37 15297:17-25
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./main.js
```

and a warning

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/hash-stream-validation/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fast-crc32c' in 'XXX/node_modules/hash-stream-validation'
 @ ./node_modules/hash-stream-validation/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./main.js
```

If I manually add those dependencies to the project, I then get

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/fast-crc32c/loader.js 8:20-33
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/hash-stream-validation/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./main.js
```

I raised a GitHub issue with Firebase (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/829) but they don't see it as an issue.

I'm not clear right now if I can progress safely by ignoring the remaining warning or if it will bite me later. Can anyone explain, aside from excluding the dependency from Webpack, what the possible solutions are to this?

Comment: I assume you are using dynamic requires
look at these webpack issues
[Issue 196](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196)
[Issue 198](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/198)

Comment: @YoussefAbouEgla I'm not, but I guess Firebase are. Do you know of any way around the issue without fixing upstream?

Comment: I believe this isn't in firebase but in `/fast-crc32c/loader.js 8:20-33`
a work around would be to fork it and fix the issue
I found this post on medium which might also help [webpack and dynamic imports](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234)

Comment: Webpack will require eagerly all the requires, which may have circular dependency at static time, but not in run time, for example if (someCondition) {
  require('some-file');
}

at run time maybe won't require the file, but webpack will bundle it.